# Cloud application multi tenancy

Tags: database, azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, multi-tenant

I have an PHP application that can be used by one organization (multi users). I would like to transfer the application to the cloud and convert it to serve multi organizations.

Each organization will have its own private data stored in the DB. 
What would be the best technique to convert it to serve multi organization? Is it having a separate DB for each organization? 
Please note that the application is using 140+ tables in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'best' way, because there is no universal definition of what 'best' is. Best for cost? best for performance? best for flexibility? but here is a talk given last month at AWS Reinvent that discussed this very issue and gives you some things to think about:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMP0leGZpo4

Comment: Right, would be best for cost and performance. or the common technique that's been widely used. Thanks.